# Java animation about reframing an image

Tags: java, animation, 2d, physics

Hi I am currently making a program that will show a spring that moves with the values that I enter and uses the formulas of physics. The problem is that, when I create a spring and make the animation start, the old image stays there and overrides without deleting the one before here's the code of the problem :

```
bouton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            /*anime.animer();
              anime.repaint();*/

            for (int t = 0; t < 500; t += 5) {
                for (int i = 105; i < 175; i += 5) {
                    Ellipse2D elp1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(i, 100, 15, 30);
                    ((Graphics2D) dessinPanel.getGraphics()).draw(elp1);


                }
                for (int i = 105; i < 175; i += 5) {
                    Ellipse2D elp1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(i, 100, 15 + osi.simuler(t), 30);
                    ((Graphics2D) dessinPanel.getGraphics()).draw(elp1);
                    dessinPanel.repaint();

                    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(186 + osi.simuler(t), 90, 50, 50);
                    ((Graphics2D) dessinPanel.getGraphics()).draw(rect);
                    dessinPanel.repaint();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Here`s also some pictures to show the problem:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On1GG.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9KCF.png)

Comment: That is not how you paint shapes.  Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.  Also, you cannot sleep in an event handler or paint method;  you must call repaint() from a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)‘s event handler instead (not a java.util.Timer!).

Answer (score 0):

You need to decouple your painting from your value adjustments.

Your painting operation should start by clearing the background, then paint the spring and box using the current input values.

When an input value changes, simply update the variable and invalidate() the display area.

For better performance, clearing the background can also be done by drawing the spring and box at their current positions in the background color.  This also makes the updating of the input values more difficult.

One more technique you might use would be to widen the brush and draw first in the background color, then shrink the brush and draw the actual spring and rectangle in their correct form.  This would be equivalent to erasing the background as long as you control the amount either can move in a single frame.